# Not able to run mongodump

Tags: mongodb

I have created two users with below roles on my mongoinstance

```
use mydb
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "dbUser",
    pwd: "dbPassword",
    roles: [ { role: "dbOwner", db: "mydb" } ]
  }
)


use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "adminUser",
    pwd: "adminPassword",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

MongoDb is up & running using above credentials, Now when i try to take mongodump using below command in terminal

```
mongodump --host localhost --port 27017 -u dbUser -p dbPassword --authenticationDatabase mydb
```

i am getting below error, not able to resolve this

```
connected to: localhost:27017
assertion: 13 not authorized on admin to execute command { getParameter: 1, authSchemaVersion: 1 }
```

Any idea? where i am doing wrong?

Comment: Your permissions aren't strong enough. `dbUser` is `dbOwner` on `mydb` but you are dumping the whole instance.

Comment: Yeah you are right.. passing -d mydb resolved issue

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As suggested by @wdberkeley, problem got resolved by passing db name as parameter

below command runs fine

```
mongodump --host localhost --port 27017 -u dbUser -p dbPassword -d mydb
```

Answer (score 8):

mongodump is not a Mongo shell command, it's an operating system command.

Just like you run mongo.exe to start the shell from OS prompt, you should run mongodump the same way from OS prompt. Example:

```
mongodump --host localhost --port 27017 -u dbUser -p dbPassword --authenticationDatabase mydb
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for reply, i know that. I will edit my question to make it clear

Comment: --authenticationDatabase did a trick for me as my user was created in "admin"database

Answer (score 0):

userAdminAnyDatabase is not enough to do mongodump on all the dbs that's why you are getting this error. You will need a super user that has:

```
userAdminAnyDatabase
readWriteAnyDatabase
clusterAdmin
```

privileges to run mongodump on all dbs.

OR you just need 'backup' privilege

```
db.grantRolesToUser('username', [{
  role: 'backup',
  db: 'name of ur authentication db'
}])
```